# Using MagicalRecord and NSXMLParser in a background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, magicalrecord

I'm using an NSXMLParser to process a large and complex XML file that needs to end up in my Core Data model. To do this I am following the design pattern as discussed in the iOS book by Conway and Hillegass, where the delegate of the NSXMLParser is changed every time a new node is reached and new nodes are created on the fly. To create the entities, I am using MagicalRecord's `MR_createEntity` for each new node during the parsing to set up my data model. After the parsing is finished I call

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

to save the new entities to my Core Data store.

This all works fine, until I recently decided to move the parsing into a background thread. And I noticed the XML data was not always imported. So after some Googling I found that `MR_createEntity` should not be used on a background thread (link: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/298).

So what to do? I see two possible solutions:

1. During the parsing, just create a Foundation based structure of all the nodes, a mixture of NSDictionaries and NSArrays. This can be done on a background thread.  Once done, I go back to the main thread and save my data into Core Data using `MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject` or something similar (as described here: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/). But will that work with combinations of deeply nested dictionaries and arrays?
2. During the parsing, instead of calling `MR_CreateEntity`, I use

   ```
   [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
   {
       MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
   }];
   ```

every time I come upon a new node as suggested in the github link above.

So before I start cutting up and modifying my code, what would be the way to go? Maybe there is another approach?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the MagicalRecord source code correctly, you need only a *single*
`saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion:` call:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
      // ... parse XML ...
      // ... create entities with:
      MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
      // ...
} completion:^{
    NSLog("Import finished");
}];
```

This

- creates a temporary background context,
- executes the first block on the background queue associated with that context,
- calls `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` to save the temporary context to the 
  main context *and* save the main context to the persistent core,
- and finally executes the completion block.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above, and I can see all the code being executed, but in my completion block I end up with "success = NO, and error = nil"  (saveInBackgroundWithBlock is deprecated, and the replacement saveWithBlock has a BOOL and NSError in the completion block). So the data was not saved to the store. I am also using [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] to get the localContext when creating each entity. Maybe that's wrong?

Comment: @Koen: `saveWithBlock:completion` *should* work as well, but  "success = NO, and error = nil" is strange, I have no idea why that could happen. However, I would avoid using `MR_contextForCurrentThread` (compare the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814656/passing-a-managedcontext-with-core-date-magical-record). You should use the `localContext` passed to the block.

Comment: I am now passing the local context along with the parser by giving all entities a context property, and now it works. Still not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it (as opposed to proposal 1. in my original question). I'll look at it again later today or after the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924299/1979953

like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  // dispatch_async mean your NSXMLParser in a backgound thread
  MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createEntity];

  ...

  [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] saveNestedContexts];
});
```

but, you found that MR_createEntity should not be used on a background thread. So I'm confused.